# App inventor 2 open browsers (Firefox and Edge) with specific URL

Tags: android, android-intent, app-inventor

I need to make an application in App inventor 2 that displays the website in the selected browser when clicked. I was able to do this for google chrome, but it doesn't work on firefox and edge. The firefox application starts up but does not enter the link. The Edge application does not turn on at all.

This is code for chrome browser:
[image: THis is code for ch]

This is edge:
[image]

This is Firefox (App starting but not search)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want your user to use a specific browser, I think a better approach would just be opening the link in the user's default browser. If they don't have a default browser, then Android should show the browser chooser.

[image: Screenshot of App Inventor blocks]

Comment: Unfortunately, the application has to open the appropriate browsers